# WSS connection with ActiveMQ

Tags: linux, ssl, websocket, activemq-classic, cpanel

I'm trying to connect to ActiveMQ via WebSocketSecure and i'm runing out of ideas

sslContext
[image: this is the sslContext]

transportConnector
[image: this is the transportConnector]

activemq start output
[image: this is the activemq start output]

activemq log output
[image: this is the activemq log output]

trying to connect using default credentials
[image: this is me trying to connect using default credentials]

ws works fine, once I change to wss and add the sslContext everything goes to hell

Comment: Not an answer, but I ended up doing the TLS part in a Nginx proxy and plain WS Ngnix-ActiveMQ once. That worked and kept the ActiveMQ setup clean and I could share common external facing web site stuff in the Nginx config.

Comment: If you highlight your text in Putty it will automatically be copied to your clipboard, at least with the default settings

Comment: What does "everything goes to hell" mean, error message ?  How does the client side get configured with the correct certificate to send?  Don't see anything on that web console to do that

Comment: "everything goes to hell" error message is in the last screenshot: handshake cancelled

Comment: Please provide the outputs as text and state the errors. The text on the picture is too small to read. In addition, the text cannot be indexed by search engines for future visitors.

Comment: Note that the "ActiveMQ start output" screenshot is actually the stop screenshot.  Posting the logs from the whole run of activemq (including an attempted connection) would be helpful.